# External service fires asynchronous task and immediately returns. How to tell when the tasks are actually finished?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I need to call some services and know when they are finished, so that I can send out notification:

```
...
someService.doStuff();
otherService.doStuff();
//all services finished
sendOutNotification();
```

The problem is that some of these services are firing off their work asynchronously and returning from doStuff() immediately, not waiting for those work to finish.  Since my current thread is simply calling these service methods, rather than owning any actual thread managing executors that these services are creating and firing, it seems like there is no way to know when the threads fired by doStuff() are finished.

Is there a way to get around this?  Or is there a design issue here chaining asynchronous executions with no waiting in any level (except the top)?

Comment: it's async, so you'd need a callbank function that the jobs can fire when they complete. that or go into a polling loop and have the jobs set a flag when they're done.

Comment: the API should provide a way to notify the completion of the action.

Answer (score 0):

When you get to a point you must not pass before all the async work is done, you need either to poll for completion of the async tasks, or to have some mechanism for blocking on their completion.

A decent way to approach this is to execute your tasks via an `ExecutorService`, and provide the resulting `Future` objects to the main thread as handles.  That is, your `doStuff()` methods would return these.  Your main method collects the `Future`s, and when the time comes it can poll via `Future.isDone()`, block on completion via `Future.get()`, and more.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use "callbacks". So when you call the external service, send the service listeners (if the external service supports this type of contract.) The callbacks, or listeners, are called by the external service on completion.

Otherwise, you could use those APIs with futures. Using `.get()` you can check the completion status of them. To sync their operations, you can use a countdown latch so that when all threads return, the countdown latch becomes 0 and you can take actions.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to : http://markusjais.com/understanding-java-util-concurrent-completionservice/

May be Java's Completion Service can do stuff for u if ext lib dont support call backs.

Submit all your `doStuff` tasks to completion service and use `take()` for all the tasks. Once `take()` returns for all submitted tasks (which gets blocked unless there is element in queue that completion service puts after task is completed)

Once `take()` returns for all tasks , you can trigger notify.